# Inconsistent result from isnumeric

Tags: sql-server, isnumeric

I have the following queries.

```
    select ISNUMERIC(result+ 'E0'), from t1  
    select ISNUMERIC('7' + 'E0') 
    select ISNUMERIC('7' + '.E0')
```

The data type of result column is varchar(50).The first query yields 0 even when result is  like 2,3 and returns 1 for float only ...Whereas second and third query works fine for both integer and float.Am I missing anything? My requirement is to check whether result column is number(integer,float) or not.I know isnumeric returns 1 for type like money,small money,real etc but this is not the case here as i don't have such type in my result and i am only receiving 0.

Comment: have a look in here: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6423

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the seemingly inconsistent result might be, that there is a space in your result column value. Try timming text and feed the trimmed text to ISNUMERIC:

```
select ISNUMERIC(ltrim(rtrim(result))+ 'E0') from t1
```

Comment: Thanks.You are right it's because of space. It works but when I tried to copy the cell data and paste in notepad and other editor  I could not find space.